# How to Remove Azure Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Tags: http-headers, azure-web-app-service

Posts to my Azure Web App are being replied to with additional Http Header information, specifically the following:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Request-Context
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=xxx;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=ws.caxxx
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:xxx
```

This appears to be due to Custom Domains configured on my site, i.e., the Azure site url is xxx.azurewebsites.net and I have a Custom Domain set ws.xxx.com.  I say that because when I'm posting to the Azure url I do not see the Access-Control-Expose-Headers and the Request-Context lines in the headers.

I do not have CORS configured for this site, so I don't know why I am getting the Access-Control-Expose-Headers.

Note that this is the Production site.  I have another Testing site where I do not have this problem!  So there must be something with my Azure configuration.

On my Testing site, I can remove the ARRAffinity cookie by adding the httpProtocol clause  to the web.config.  However, when added to the Production site it throws a 500 error.

The posting devices are IoT devices, so I need to reduce the headers sent back to the devices.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> The Access-Control-Expose-Headers header is used by browsers to expose response headers that are not allowed by default in a cross-origin request.

It allows the browser to access additional information from the server response. If you want to remove this header from your Azure Web App, you can follow these steps:

1. Open the Azure portal and navigate to your Web App.
2. Click on "Configuration" under the "Settings" section.
3. Scroll down to the "Application settings" section and click on "New application setting".
   Enter "WEBSITE_HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS" as the name and leave the value blank.
4. Click "OK" to save the setting.

As shown in the below snippet.

[image]

Application setting with `Null` value.

[image]

This will remove the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header from your Web App's responses.

If you want to remove other headers like the `Set-Cookie` or `Request-Context` headers, you may need to modify your application code or server configuration. You can also check by adding the following code to your `web.config` file to remove the `Set-Cookie` header.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <remove name="Set-Cookie" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

You can remove the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header by using the Azure Application Gateway to rewrite the header.

And you can use the Azure Application Gateway to rewrite HTTP headers and URL.

1. Create a rewrite rule with a condition that evaluates if the header in the response contains Access-Control-Expose-Headers.
2. Perform an action to remove the header.

For further information check the [MSDoc.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url.md)